# Limiting characters to be placed in a cell from a VLOOKUP function?

Tags: regex, excel, google-sheets, split, vlookup

We are doing inventory and using some VLOOKUP functions to pull information from our database. I've come a long way in setting up the sheets we will be using. However, for the Length and Width of the Slabs we have, I would want to also pull the information either from the DATABASE sheet, or from the same sheet, under the DESCRIPTION column.

Basically, I need columns `N` and `O` to be filled automatically with the appropriate information from the description of the item (column `H` in the same sheet), which is only **L X W**, always as the first piece of information for any item in our database, or column `H`.

I've tried data validation rules but it only works to tell me it is invalid, I need the cell to be cleared automatically of any unwanted characters.

I thought about SPLIT function using the `X` as a delimiter , but it won't work well as I have to bring back the sheet to Excel later.

UPDATE: Sorry folks I will upload an image of the entire sheet. `F27` is the "Product Code", which is used to pull the description, class 1, class 2, and U/M from the database. I can either pull `L X W` from the database as well, or pull it from description from within the same sheet

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

TEST SHEET BELOW:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1StOWs0sTsdIUT76tKVvdjGHW7s-PXSNA1ceIQsYsFFY

[image: what I want to automate]

Comment: What is in `F27`? It is not in your image. Please share a test sheet

Comment: How have you implemented your data validation? (Under the `Data > Data Validation` menu item)

Comment: “Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?” Not without a sheet we don’t ;-)

Comment: Sorry folks I will upload an image of the entire sheet. F27 is the "Product Code", which is used to pull the description, class 1, class 2, and U/M from the database. I can either pull L X W from the database as well, or pull it from description from within the same sheet.

Comment: Despite your edits, images still miss vital info. Please share a [test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) or any answer will be on the air.

Comment: @marikamitsos Hi Mark, thank you for trying to help. I will upload a test sheet now.  Link has been added to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula in cell `N5`:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(H5:H11,"(\d+[X|x]\d+)"),"X|x",1,1)))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: This worked absolutely flawlessly! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: *"This worked absolutely flawlessly"* You can also accept the answer. :)